# Платонизм, антоним [Как это называется?]

Tags: терминология

И снова здравствуйте.

Очередной вопрос из цикла.

В этот раз речь пойдёт о следующем: существует такое понятие как "Платоническая любовь" - основанная на духовном, чистом, прекрасном, искреннем и тд.
Так вот, а как же будет называться обратная (противоположная) "любовь" - привязанность на плоти, страсти, вожделении и т.п.
Термин "Материализм" не подходит, слишком абстрактно.
Страсть ? - В принципе да, но это одно из составляющих, не ёмкое понятие.
В общем - с нетерпением жду Ваших мыслей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Антоним платонической любви  - это плотская любовь, которая проявляется чисто  в физическом влечении.

Если плотскую любовь совместить с  духовной близостью, то получится любовь эротическая. Эрос –  это символ стихийной, страстной влюблённости, направленный на телесное обладание.  Здесь также Физиологический компонент очень важен, но он не единственный, или кажется не единственным.

Такое чувство вспыхивает как  пламя и может казаться любовью в классическом ее понимании, с теми же эмоциями и душевными страданиями.  "Но узнаю по всем приметам болезнь любви в душе моей", - писал А. Пушкин. Но о том же говорил и платонический Петрарка: "Коль не любовь сей жар, какой недуг Меня знобит? Коль он - любовь, то что же Любовь? Добро ль?.. Но эти муки, Боже!..Так злой огонь?.. А сладость этих мук!"

Comment: То что искал, спасибо.

Comment: Вы, София, надо думать, смерти моей хотите...

Comment: Я как раз в процессе письма с тревогой думала о Вас.

Comment: Забавно, что само греческое имя Платон означает "плотный, широкоплечий". То есть "платонизм" и "плотская любовь" формально одно и то же.))))

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно поняла суть Ваших духовных поисков, замечу, что, по-моему, никто не спорит с тем, что определением понятия "страстная любовь" является такой род отношений, который совмещает в себе и духовную близость, и половое влечение. Если же кто-то сможет описать это явление одним словом - обещаю зарезаться бритвой Оккама.

Answer (score 0):

**Вожделение**,
 если имеются в виду чувства конкретного человека и **секс без 
обязательств**, если подразумеваются отношения пары.

---

Следующая стадия после платонической - *чувственные отношения*.

Комментарии оставлять к сожалению не могу, так как пишу с мобильника.

Comment: Подразумевалась уже пройденная стадия платонизма, перешедшая в фазу тех определяемых отношений, в которых существует и половой контакт.